# Delete specified files in filelistbox using command button

Tags: vba

So I have a DirListBox, DriveListBox and a FileListBox on my form.
I also have a Delete Command Button. What I want to do is to delete a *.docx file that is shown on my FileListBox when I press the Delete Command Button.  Here's my code:

```
Private Sub cmddel1_Click()
Dim nAns As Long
Dim strFile As String
If flb1.ListIndex < 0 Then
  'There is nothing selected in the listbox.
   Exit Sub
End If

strFile = flb1.Path & flb1.List(flb1.ListIndex)

 'Give them a chance to not delete the file
nAns = MsgBox("Please confirm to delete file ' " & strFile & "'?'", vbQuestion & vbYesNo)
 'If they choose Yes then delete the file.
If nAns = vbYes Then
  kill (flb1.path)
  End If
End Sub
```

Say that `flb1` is the name of my FileListBox.

Here is my DirListBox code:

```
Private Sub Dir1_Change()
flb1.Path = Dir1.Path
End Sub
```

and here is the DriveListBox Code:

```
Private Sub Drive1_Change()
Dir.Path = Drive1.Drive
End Sub
```

The problem that occurs is when I press the Delete Command Button, it runs up to the `nAns =  nAns = MsgBox("Please confirm to delete file ' " & strFile & "'?'", vbQuestion & vbYesNo)` and when I press yes an `Run-Time Error '53' File Not Found` and the debug is on the `kill (flb1.path)`.

What should I use to delete the .docx file shown on the Filelistbox when I click the "Delete" command button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only referring to the Path not the actual file itself.

You can use the following:

```
Kill strFile
or
Kill (strFile)
```

Code example:

```
Sub Killfl()
    Dim flpath As String
    Dim flname As String
    Dim strFile As String
    flpath = "c:\Test\"
    flname = "Test.txt"
    strFile = flpath & flname
    Kill strFile
End Sub
```

The above code deletes a `File` with `File Extension .txt` called `Test.txt` in `C:\Test\`

Comment: Hi, I've changed it to `kill strfile` but the same error popsup `Run-Time Error '53' File Not Found`

Comment: Is `flb1.List(flb1.ListIndex)` collecting the filename including filetype? If not you still need to add the filetype extension to the string

Comment: can you show an example of how your strFile looks like?

Comment: Note that I am trying to delete a *.docx file type shown on a file list box, what I want to do is not specify the path or directory of C:\ what I would like is to delete a .docx file through the filelistbox by using the path of DirListBox

Comment: @E.Cristoph I understand what your doing, but for a simple example I posted above code. if you replace it with your code it still works I do not however have your wb to test your exact code. That shouldn't matter as it works the same.

Comment: I've tried to put the codes in that you listed, i've changed `flpath="c:\asd\"` and `flname="asd.docx"` although the same error pop-ups.

Comment: is the File then actually in that location? I have tested my code and it works fine, i double checked even if it would delete .docx and it does. It will work for any filetype.

Comment: It worked! Is there a way to change the flpath to use my Drive1(DriveListBox)?

Comment: you can do exactly as you had it, `Kill strFile` <- as long as the correct `String` is parsed to the `Kill command`. That's why i asked for what is the `String` your `Msgbox` generates. If the String is incorrect it won't be able to delete the file. (I figured the String is missing something a \ or something else causing the error)

Comment: Thanks for helping me! Everything works great now! Thank you so much!